# Problem using JNI - Error when generating header file

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I used the following guide to get started, http://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/jni/beginning-jni-win.html.

But when I try to generate the header file using the command below

> JAVA_HOME\bin\javah.exe -o
>   HelloWorldNative.h -jni 
>   -classpath PROJECTS_ROOT\HelloWorld\build\classes
>   helloworld.Main

I get the following error.

> Error: Can't recover from an I/O
>   error with the following message:
>   HelloWorldNative.h (access denied)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to me like you are standing in a directory where you are not granted write access when you run javah.

**Edit:** What if you specify a full path to somewhere you know you have write access?

Comment: Almost embarrassing I didnt try running as admin ^^
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also got that problem and this is how I solved it:

After building your project,go to the directory where your .class files are.

e.g C:\Users\Development\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DLLDevelopment\build\classes

and run your command again.